# Navigation bar Items Positioning

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Good Day,
I'm learning web development and I want to create a simple website with a navigation bar using HTML and CSS. However when I hover on the navigation bar the links shift which is what I don't want. I still want the circle border to show up when I hover but I don't want the items to shift. See my code below:

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <!--Specifies language and type of characters to use-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> <!--Defines metadata about an object-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!--Specifies name as viewport and content gives the visible area of your webpage on your device-->
    <meta name="keyword" content=""> <!--Assist in search engine optimization of your webpage-->
    <meta name="description" content=""> <!--Gives your webpage a description-->
    <base href=""> <!--Has to do with document root and where the very first webpage of your site is located-->
    <title>New Web</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"> <!--External css styling-->
    <style>
        
    </style> <!--Embedded css styling-->
</head>
    <body>
        <header class="fixed-nav">
        <a href="index.html"> <img class="img" src="images/img5.PNG"></a>
            <ul class="topmenu">
                <li><a class="links" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="links" href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a class="links" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a class="links" href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
.fixed-nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: blue !important; /*important clause prevents any other styling from overriding this one*/
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
        }
.img{
    width:60px;
    height:50px;
    top:2px;
    /*background:url('images/img6.png') transparent;*/
    left:5px;
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    
    
    
}
.topmenu{
list-style-type:none;
float:right;

}
.topmenu li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    
}
.links{
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:whitesmoke;
    font-weight:bold;
    

   
  
    
}

.links:hover {
  color: rgb(7, 66, 7);
 /*  width:50px;
  height:50px; */
    border-radius: 50%; 
   border-style: solid; 
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(81,203,238,0.5); 
  box-sizing:content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  /* padding: 14px 16px; */
}
#wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh; /*similar to 100%*/
    background-image: url(images/img1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
     
}
```

I would appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Simulator: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xzz1qs?file=index.html)

here in the code, I have done some CSS style changes, along with that I have added `nav` tag instead of `header`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.fixed-nav {
  /* position: fixed; */
  /* top: 0;
  left: 0; */
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  /* z-index: 1000; */
  background-color: blue !important;
  /*important clause prevents any other styling from overriding this one*/
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: 50px;
}

.img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 2px;
  /*background:url('images/img6.png') transparent;*/
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  /* display: block; */
}


/* .topmenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
} */

.topmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.links {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.links:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 212, 209);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0.5);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  /* padding: 14px 16px; */
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /*similar to 100%*/
  background-image: url(images/img1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--Specifies language and type of characters to use-->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--Defines metadata about an object-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--Specifies name as viewport and content gives the visible area of your webpage on your device-->
  <meta name="keyword" content="">
  <!--Assist in search engine optimization of your webpage-->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <!--Gives your webpage a description-->
  <base href="">
  <!--Has to do with document root and where the very first webpage of your site is located-->
  <title>New Web</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <!--External css styling-->
  <style>

  </style>
  <!--Embedded css styling-->
</head>

<body>
  <header class="fixed-nav">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img class="img" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hdnicewallpapers.com%2FWalls%2FBig%2FNature%2520and%2520Landscape%2FBeautiful_Sunrising_Nature_Image.jpg&f=1&nofb=1"></a>
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li><a class="links" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, while testing your `Developer tools` are the best guide and it's easy to analyse from there.